# Does "trotzdem/obwohl" look more friendly and informal than "trotz" in this context?

Tags: formality, informal, context

> Wie du ja weißt, bin ich zum ersten Mal Ski gefahren. Es hat viel Spaß gemacht, **trotz** der fürchterlichen Angst, die ich erst vor den Abhängen  gehabt habe.
>
> Wie du ja weißt, bin ich zum ersten Mal Ski gefahren. Es hat viel Spaß gemacht, **obwohl** ich erst fürchterliche Angst vor den Abhängen gehabt habe.
>
> Wie du ja weißt, bin ich zum ersten Mal Ski gefahren. Es hat viel Spaß gemacht, **trotzdem** ich erst fürchterliche Angst vor den Abhängen gehabt habe.

Comment: _"trotzdem/obwohl die starke Steigungen mir fürchtlichen Angst erst mal gemacht haben"_ isn't even remotely correct german language. You're not asking here for proofreading your homework again, do you?

Comment: You already were pointed out several times, what's wrong and not useful with question patterns like these. Nuff said.

Comment: "Ich" schreiben die Briten groß, wir bescheidenen Deutschen nicht. Angst ist fürchterlich, Ski kann man fahren und laufen - es gibt auch Skiwandern, aber weniger an Abhängen - an den Abfällen (Mannerschnitten) vielleicht aber doch. Spaß, Substantiv, groß.

Comment: @userunknown Das mit dem Editieren habe ich auch schon _"fruchtlos"_ versucht. Es ist ja nicht mal klar was überhaupt in Frage, oder der Kontext ist.

Comment: @userunknown Aber wer bin ich schon, dass ich meine Zweifel an der Nützlichkeit von _@HussienChahin_ s Fragen konstatiere :-P ...

Comment: @userunknown Du weisst wie Du mich kontaktieren kannst, wenn irgendwelche Fragen auftauchen sollten ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Ich finde, auch eine Frage die man eigentlich abschießen will, sollte man vorher hübsch frisieren, denn die Frage soll nicht an ihrer ungelenken Präsentation scheitern, sondern daran, dass sie im Kern nicht taugt. Eine holprige Frage kostet auch gerne mal 20 Leser 1 Minute extra, so dass selbst die Investition von 10 Minuten gerechtfertigt scheint. Die Frage lautet m.E.: Stimmt es, dass 'obwohl' und 'trotzdem' weicher wirken als 'trotz'. Diese Frage baut schon auf einer fragilen Prämisse auf. Ich vermute, der Spaß hängt ganz entscheidend mit der Gefahr zusammen. Nicht trotz …

Comment: … sondern durch die Angst, wegen der Angst, macht es Spaß. Angst, Streß, Endorphine, Hormone, Rausch. Freundlicher oder weicher finde ich keine der Formulierungen.

Answer (score 2):

Neither friendliness nor formality are affected by the choice. Thus the answer to the question is **no**.

Anyhow, the second and the third constructions sound more fluent. Aside from that, the first construction is ambiguous. The word *erst* in

> ... trotz der fürchterlichen Angst, die ich **erst** vor den Abhängen gehabt habe ...

can mean *initially* (*anfänglich*) or *at first* (*zunächst*) when it refers to the anxiety. So, you were anxious at first about the slopes, but later you were not axious anymore. However, *erst* can also mean *not untill*, that is, you were anxious not untill you reached the slopes. Actually, I would have interpreted it this way, if I had not known your intention, because it is not clear that *erst* refers to the anxiety.